# UV Mapping onto mesh generated with Geometry Nodes

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes

I'm struggling to place a UV map in the indicated position of this bottle. I have tried several adjustments on the mapping nodes but still not getting it right.[image]

Anyone to assist, maybe with a trick or combination of extra nodes i have to use to have it fixed?

[image]

Comment: The bottle is created with Geometry Nodes by rotating a profile curve. It's very similar to the *Screw* modifier approach. For the label area, you need a UV map. I don't know if this is possible For curves it's possible to calculate a UV map and expose this from GN to the shader (https://blenderartists.org/t/can-i-create-uv-in-geometry-nodes/1343499/17). And the primitive GNs (cylinder, sphere, cube, ...) come with a UV map. (It's the "uv_map" attribute in the *Face Corner* domain.) Maybe you could use this or a UV map of a cylinder object and transfer it? I have no idea if that could work.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try and see if it can work.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind extra geometry for the bottle label you can create it inside the geometry node tree with a *Cylinder* node and shrink-wrap it with the *Raycast* node.

[image: geometry node tree]

The primitive cylinder from the *Cylinder* node has a UV map (*uv_map*) in the *Face Corner* domain. You can use this vector map in the material to map an image texture.

[image: material]

(In the example, I've reduced the number of generated geometry by deactivating the curve resampling and lowering the resolution. I'm guess you need the high poly count for the morphing effect?)

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.